# PHP Include fails when it contains code

Tags: php, include, xampp

I have a file I require_once: `meow.php` from within `mix.php`. I guarantee the path is correct. When meow.php is empty or only has comments - mix.php functions as expected. However, when I put any PHP code into meow.php- class or function, `mix.php` fails. If I put plain code outside of a function, `mix.php` fine. I don't understand what is wrong. This is really bizarre.

Running XAMP on OSX 10.11.6. PHP 5.6.19.

Comment: There's probably something wrong with the code in `meow.php`. Are there any error messages in the server log?

Comment: There will be an error in your PHP error_log file -- please review that error, and if you still need help, include that error with your question.

Answer (score 0):

Stupid programmer tricks. File was included twice. I went to the wrong php errors file ( native mac osx vs xampp ) which is why I didn't find it. Sorry about that.